# view_get_views returns null

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have a module function which needs to get the raw results of a view, so I use this bit of code:

```
$view = views_get_view('sluitingsuren_bakker');
  $view->preview();

  return $view->result;
```

The views machine name is sluitingsuren_bakker. I also tried some other views, but it seems the module can't find any of the views.

Also I set my permissions on this view to none, because I thought that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the display name, which is the machine name of the block/page.

You can find the machine name under Advanced settings in the right side of the view.

try:

```
   <?php 
    $view = views_get_view(view_name);
    $view->set_display(machine_name);
    $view->preview();
    return $view->result
    ?>
```

[image]